# A request match too many endpoints for two Web Apis in net core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.0

I have a solution made in .net core 3.0

The solution have 2 proyects, each proyect is a Web Api.

Lets call web api `A` with the following controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("")]
public class DummyPersonController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("persons")]
    public async Task<bool> Send([FromBody] Domain.Person person)
    {

        var result = await _personManager.Send(person);

        return result;
    }
}
```

This webApi is running on localhost lets say port 5001.

Then, I run on another VS2019 the same solution but I run the other web Api, `B`, lets say it runs on port 6000

The controller is as follows:

```
[Route("")]
[ApiController]
public class PersonController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("persons")]
    public async Task<IList<Domain.Person>> SendPerson(PersonRequest personRequest)
    {
        return new List<Domain.Person> { new Domain.Person() };
    }
}
```

If I use Postman to make a `POST` to `https://localhost:5001/persons` then it is obvious that there are more than one place where the request can land, but what buggers me is that, those are two different ports.

How can I take into consideration the ports when I make a `POST` to `/persons`?

Comment: Every web resquest class has a field or property for "port". It is as integral a part of the request as the IP adress. Often you can just define it in the URL. One number is just usually *implied* based on the Protocoll used, but of course it can be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Every Networking class has a field or property for the port number. If no number is specified, a default port number is implied based on the protocoll. That is where [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) comes in.

Moreover the URL Shema allows you to declare the port to be used, as part of host part of the URL (same rule for defaults):

http://localhost:3000/

This will query localhost on port 3000, rather then 80 (the default for http is 80, with fallbacks at 8080 and 8008. HTTPS defaults to 443).

So it depends a bit on the classes you got and how much of the URL you write and/or store.

Answer (score 0):

When you call https://localhost:5001/persons you are only ever calling Web Api "A" because you've specified the port.

If you called https://localhost/persons then IIS or whatever webhost you're using would look to see if there was an application bound to port 443 since you are passing an https request and route the traffic to that application.

Similarly if you called http://localhost/persons then IIS or whatever webhost you're using would look to see if there was an application bound to port 80 since you are passing an plain http request and route the traffic to that application.

In your cases you have 2 apps bound to separate ports and there is no ambiguity about which application will be called when you specify the ports in postman.

If you need to switch ports when making a call to these api's then you'll need to set the port in your client code at the time you are making the call. If you neglect to specify the port then it will be up to your web host to decide which application will get the traffic based on which application you have bound to port 443.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the problem was that Web Api `B` had a dependency with Web Api `A`, I did this in order to use the same `Domain classes`, which would be a good idea to have them in a different proyect. Anyways, when you run the Web Api with the dependency it also runs the other controller and this causes the issue.

Comment: For sharing `Domian classes`, you could create a new separate class intead of referencing the Project A directly.